# Time Limit Error On CodeChef

Tags: c++, algorithm

[This Is The Question](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO13003)

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned long numberOfGums;
    unsigned long hardnessLimit;
    unsigned long counter = 0;

    cin >> numberOfGums;
    cin >> hardnessLimit;

    unsigned long gums[numberOfGums];

    for(unsigned long i=0; i<numberOfGums; i++){
        cin >> gums[i];
    }

    for(unsigned long i=0; i<numberOfGums; i++){
        if(gums[i] < hardnessLimit){
            for(unsigned long j=i+1; j<numberOfGums; j++){
                if((gums[i] + gums[j]) < hardnessLimit){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program is giving me **TLE(Time Limit Exceeded)** error, due to which i am getting only 30 points out of 100. To be specific, this program is unable to complete **subtask-2** worth the rest 70 marks (given on the problem page).

I have tried stuff like using *printf* and *scanf* instead of *cin* and *cout*, but the program still isn't fast enough.

What can i do to improve this program, or what is a better approach to this problem.

I tried this also, but got the same error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long numberOfGums;
    long hardnessLimit;
    long counter = 0;
    long temp = 0;

    cin >> numberOfGums;
    cin >> hardnessLimit;

    long gums[numberOfGums];

    for(long i=0; i<numberOfGums; i++){
        cin >> temp;
        if(temp < hardnessLimit){
            gums[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(long i=0; i<numberOfGums; i++){
        if(gums[i] != -1){
            for(long j=i+1; (j<numberOfGums); j++){
                if(((gums[i] + gums[j]) < hardnessLimit) && gums[j] != -1){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << counter << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because this is perhaps a brute force solution which can be optimized. You have a o(n^2) complexity solution when numberOfGums can be as large as 100,000.

Comment: what better approach do you suggest, sorting the array or something?

Comment: Please remove the C tag, this is in no way valid C code

Comment: Always try to figure out what you can gain from sorting the input data.

Comment: The time limit is 1 sec only, so i don't think i should be sorting the array after taking the input, if there is someway to do it while taking the input, pls suggest

Comment: @Virus Why don't you think sorting the array wouldn't work?  An O(n*n) solution as you posted is far slower than sorting and then binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is `O(N^2)` which will definitely time out given the constraints.

A more efficient solution is an `O(NlogN)` solution. This is the basic outline of the algorithm:

- Sort the array. This takes `O(NlogN)` time.
- Now for each element in the sorted array, say `p`, search for an element index(right of the element `p`) in the array such that the value at that index is less than `k - p`. Use binary search for this.  After finding this index, you can easily calculate the number of such pairs associated with the element `p`. This complete step takes `O(logN)` time for each element
- Do the above process for all elements in the array except for the last element as there is no array left to its right.

You will get the answer by summing up all the pairs for each element `p` that you have obtained

Hope it helps!!!

**Edit:** I am adding the C++ implementation of the above algorithm. This solution passes all the test cases on CodeChef.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int binsearch(int a[],int n, int x)
{
    int low, high, mid, k=-1;
    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(a[mid] <= x-1){
            k = mid;
            low = mid+1;
        }
        else{
            high = mid-1;
        }

    }
    return k;
}
int main() 
{
    int n, k, i, j;
    long long ans = 0;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int arr[n];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    sort(arr,arr+n);

    j = 0;

    while(j<n-1)
    {
        if(k-arr[j] > 0)
        {
            int ind = binsearch(arr,n,k-arr[j]);
            ans = ans + (ind-j>=0 ? (ind-j):0);
        }
        j++;
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It is not C++ if you;re using things like `int arr[n]`.  That is not valid C++.  Sometime a blowing out of the stack causes errors.  You should change it to `std::vector`  Also, `std::lower_bound` can be used instead of writing your own binary search.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I am not a pro in C++. I prefer to use C like syntax even in C++ when solving competitive coding questions. Looking at the author's code, its quite likely that he does not have much knowledge about vectors. So I tried to keep the solution as simple as possible from the syntax point of view.

Comment: @MrSmith42 *it is still valid c++ code* -- No it isn't. Variable length arrays were never valid C++ code and it is misleading to say that the code is correct C++. Also, it is very relevant to the problem, as there have been questions where the usage of such arrays were the cause of the problem (stack memory issues and seg faults), where a usage of std::vector solved the problem.  As can be seen [here](http://rextester.com/LINXX6069), the code fails to compile using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score -1):

**TLE(Time Limit Exceeded)** occurs when your program not running completely within the time.
In competitive Programming, TLE occurs because the program takes more time than the time constraints for an output.